# Explanation of the instructions for Line 4 of Schedule SE

Tags: united-states, taxes, self-employment

I'm trying to fill out [Schedule SE](https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/f1040sse.pdf) for 2016. I'm confused by line 4, which includes the phrase

> **don't** file this schedule unless you have an amount on line 1b.

where Line 1b is:

> If you received social security retirement or disability benefits, enter the amount of Conservation Reserve Program payments included on Schedule F, line 4b, or listed on Schedule K-1 (Form 1065), box 20, code Z

Line 1b doesn't apply to me, yet I'm pretty sure that I do have to file Schedule SE. Should I just ignore this comment?

P.S. The [instructions](https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/i1040sse.pdf) seem to refer to the "total of lines 1a and 2", which is basically what is on line 3 (given that line 1b doesn't apply to me). So I suspect that there is a typo on Schedule SE and that "line 1b" in the cited phrase should actually be "line 3"; could this be?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It needs to be taken in the context of the first part of the sentence:

> If less than $400, you don't owe self-employment tax; **don't** file this schedule unless you have an amount on line 1b

So I interpret it as: if your taxable self-employment income (Line 3 * 92.35%) is less than $400, you don't need to pay self-employment tax (and hence don't need to fill out the form) **unless** you have an amount on line 1b.